# Symfony2 - Semantical Error Relation between Entity and retrieve information

Tags: doctrine, symfony, doctrine-orm, entity-relationship

I want to make

```
$this->getEntityManager()
->createQuery(' SELECT P.*  
            FROM    MyNameSpaceProfileBundle:Tutor T
                JOIN    MyNameSpaceProfileBundle:Person Pe 
                JOIN    MyNameSpaceMediaBundle:KidContent KC
                JOIN    MyNameSpaceMediaBundle:Post P
                WHERE T.id = :id'
)->setParameter('id', $pId);
```

but I have this kind of error:

> [Semantical Error] line 0, col 128 near 'Pe ': Error: Identification
>   Variable MyNameSpaceProfileBundle:Person used in join path expression
>   but was not defined before. 500 Internal Server Error - QueryException

I have followed the tutorial from symfony2 website.

ANY help please?
See ya

I have no idea

Comment: In doctrine1.2, you would have done `T.Person Pe`, isn't it the same in doctrine2 ?

Comment: Do you mean ->createQuery(' SELECT P.*
            FROM    MyNameSpaceProfileBundle:Tutor T
                JOIN    T.Person Pe 
                JOIN    T.KidContent KC
                JOIN    KC.Post P
                WHERE T.id = :id'
)->setParameter('id', $pId); ?

Comment: I have tried: $this->getEntityManager()
      ->createQuery('
       SELECT P.* 
                 FROM  '.$this->_entityName.' P
                 JOIN  P.details KC
                 JOIN KC.creator T
                 JOIN T.information Pe
                WHERE Pe.id = :id'
       )->setParameter('id', $pId); But still have **error**

Comment: It cannot be the exact same error, since the error contains "MyNameSpaceProfileBundle:Person"

Comment: [Semantical Error] line 0, col 17 near '*
': Error: Class MyNamespace\MediaBundle\Entity\Post has no field or association named *

Comment: Ok so it's not the same error *at all* Try removing the `.*`, and please read this : http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.1/en/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html

Comment: Cool it works... It was just because of the "*"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying this makes it work:

```
$this->getEntityManager() ->createQuery(
  'SELECT P 
     FROM '.$this->_entityName.' P 
     JOIN P.details KC 
     JOIN KC.creator T 
     JOIN T.information Pe 
    WHERE Pe.id = :id' )->setParameter('id', $pId);
```